# Trouble reformatting date with as.Date

Tags: r, separator, as.date, format-string

I'm having a simple problem and I can't tell what's wrong. I'm trying to convert dates formatted "YYYY-MM-DD" to "m/d/YYYY". On my machine, this code:

```
x <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
x <- as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
print(x)
```

returns

```
"2000-01-01"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as.Date()` creates a date object where you tell it how to interpret the *input* with a `format` argument.

`format()` (or alternatively `strftime()`) will convert a date object to a character object in a desired format:

```
x <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
x
[1] "2000-01-01"

str(x)
Date[1:1], format: "2000-01-01"

y <- format(x = x,format = "%m/%d/%Y")
y
[1] "01/01/2000"

str(y)
chr "01/01/2000"

y <- strftime(x = x,format = "%m/%d/%Y")
y
[1] "01/01/2000"

str(y)
chr "01/01/2000"
```

Comment: Wouldn't `format` be more appropriate - `format(x, "%m/%d/%Y")` ?

Comment: @thelatemail You're right, that's probably more straightforward.

Comment: I would reword for clarity: "`as.Date()` converts **string input to Date output**., whereas `format()` converts **Date input to string output**. `as.Date()` will fail if you get the format separators wrong, whereas `format()` always succeeds (for a valid Date)"